# Не создаётся хранимая процедура MySQL (phpMyAdmin)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb, хранимые-процедуры

Написал SQL-запрос. Его суть заключается в том, что из таблицы **WorldSiteUrls** должно взяться 100 записей соответствующих одному условию и 5 записей соответствующих другому условию. Эти 105 записей должны поместиться во временную таблицу **tmp_SitesEnqueue**. И затем, для этих 105 сайтов в таблице **WorldSiteUrls** должно измениться значение в столбце **Dequeed**.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `tmp_SitesEnqueue` SELECT Id, Url
FROM WorldSiteUrls nolock
WHERE (Dequeed IS NULL
       OR Dequeed = 0 )
ORDER BY UpdateDate ASC
LIMIT 100;

INSERT INTO `tmp_SitesEnqueue`(Id,Url)
SELECT Id, Url
FROM WorldSiteUrls nolock
WHERE UpdateDate = '1970-01-01'
LIMIT 5;

UPDATE WorldSiteUrls as W
INNER JOIN `tmp_SitesEnqueue` as T
ON W.Id = T.Id
SET Dequeed = 1;

SELECT Url
FROM `tmp_SitesEnqueue`;
```

Запрос отрабатывает корректно.
Теперь я решил "зашить" этот запрос в хранимую процедуру и сталкиваюсь с ошибкой (на скриншоте)

[image: Скриншот ошибки]

Google не помог. Прошу помощи сообщества. Что я делаю не так?
Спасибо

Comment: DELIMITER переопределить...

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос закрыт, всем спасибо
Переопределение DELIMITER не помогло.

Решение оказалось простым - добавил BEGIN в начале и END в конце кода